# Why is it that Craigslist doesn't offer a national option for postings

Tags: craigslist

I've used craigslist multiple times for classified listings, for sale and for purchase.  If i'm looking for a good or service and am willing to travel across multiple states for the right item, I can't find it on Craigslist, unless I am willing to search every Craigslist directory from here to kingdom come.  I'm curious if there is a national craigslist site out there that let's you search ALL craigslist directories.

Answer (score 1):

The power of google will do this nicely for you. Google the following phrase to only search on Craigslist.org

Example:
site:craigslist.org + Carvin Bass Guitar + Red.

The more specific you are with what you are searching for the better your results will be. Searching for a Honda Accord this way would return thousands upon thousands of results. Maybe include the year, color and body style.

Comment: That's pretty much what I said in my answer... which I posted earlier...

Comment: You did, however you left out the search modifier "site:" to ONLY search pages from craigslist.org. You're search keywords could have referenced other sites that mention craigslist and your search keywords. Which would not be helpful to your search.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have found to do this is:

go to google.com > in the search box type in Craigslist and the items you're searching for.

Example: Craigslist Honda Accord

Now you will find every post on craigslist about a Honda Accord

Note: you might have to go through a few pages to find your results... but this is what happened I just did it:

[image]